# autodividers list view design issue using jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Hi,

I am using jQuery mobile in my demo. I made a simple example using autodividers which works fine; but, I am looking for some different type of list as shown above.

There should be Alphabetical letter, and the name should be followed by the address.

The name and the address should have brown and white background color respectively..

Is it possible to create such a list type using jQuery mobile ?

Here is what I've tried : http://jsfiddle.net/5wZ3E/1/

```
var name = new Array();
name[0] = "Saab";
name[1] = "Volvo";
name[2] = "BMW";
name[3] = "BOW";
name[4] = "BLW";

var address = new Array();
address[0] = "Sjnnnnvvf";
address[1] = "Vtyubolvo";
address[2] = "BhjhubbMW";
address[3] = "ftyui";
address[4] = "fybmi";

$(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i=0;i<name.length;i++){
        $('#folderData').append('<li><a class="lastname">'+name[i]+'</a></li>');
    }

    $("#folderData").listview({
        autodividers: true,
    });

    $('#folderData').listview('refresh');
});
```

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5wZ3E/2/ ?

Comment: yes ..80 % correct but there is > in right corner..please remove that

Comment: one more thing why there is a gap in between alphabet and row ? can i reduce that gap

Comment: Let me know if the solution I posted is ok for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Littm/LxvyU/1/

***JS:***

```
var name = new Array();
name[0] = "Saab";
name[1] = "Volvo";
name[2] = "BMW";
name[3] = "BOW";
name[4] = "BLW";

var address = new Array();
address[0] = "Sjnnnnvvf";
address[1] = "Vtyubolvo";
address[2] = "BhjhubbMW";
address[3] = "ftyui";
address[4] = "fybmi";

$(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i=0;i<name.length;i++){
        $('#folderData').append('<li><h3>'+name[i]+'</h3><p>'+address[i]+'</p></li>');
    }

    // Refreshing the list
    $('#folderData').listview('refresh');
});
```

***HTML:***

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" id="folderData" data-divider-theme="d" data-theme="d"></ul>
```

****CSS :***

```
.ui-li-static.ui-li {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

.ui-li-divider {
    background: white;
    border: none;
}

.ui-li-heading {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.ui-li-desc {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Littm'sanswer will work if you do not need an anchor tag within the li. If you want to keep the anchor as in your original question, try this:

Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5wZ3E/8/)**

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page1",function () {
    var name = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW","BOW", "BLW"];
    var address = ["Sjnnnnvvf","Vtyubolvo","BhjhubbMW","ftyui","fybmi"];

    var lItems = '';
    for(var i=0;i<name.length;i++){
      lItems += '<li data-icon="false" ><a class="lastname"><h3 class="brown">'+name[i]+'</h3><p  class="white">' + address[1] + '</p></a></li>';
    }
    $("#folderData").append($(lItems)).listview({autodividers: true}).listview('refresh');

});
```

`data-icon="false"` on the li prevents it from adding the right icon. The classes brown and white handle the styling:

```
.brown {
    background-color: #774F38 !important;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.white {
    background-color: white !important;
    padding: 8px;
}
.lastname{
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    background-color: white !important;
}
.ui-li{
    border-top: 0 !important;
}
.ui-li-divider {
    background: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
            for(var i=0;i<name.length;i++){
       $('#folderData').append(
      '<li class="test"><a class="lastname">'+address[i]+'</a></li>'
    );

     }
    $("#folderData").listview({
        autodividers: true,
        autodividersSelector:function(li){             
          return name[li.index('.test')];
        }


});
    $('#folderData').listview('refresh');
});
```

Manage css colors according to you
Cheers!!